# I can't add new application after renewing my IOS developer membership

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I renew my IOS developer membership because it was already expired to submit applications and now I can´t add new application and I really need to submit an app.
How much I need wait for add applications?

Comment: My last, it was taking a day. :D

Comment: That is my case, creating new one just take a day, but renew just one day.

Comment: ok i will wait so xD thank you

Comment: if it does, please don't forget to voteup for me :Dthanks

Comment: yes of course and by the way really aprecciate

Answer (score 0):

Usually, renewal of an expired membership takes around **a day**.
In some case it can be more, in particular if you live in a country where you need to order your membership by fax (it can take up to a week then).